# Checking to see if PowerShell Command worked, Crap Error

Tags: powershell

Needed to clean up a winmail.dat issue by adding a contact and setting a couple of parameters. All worked as shown, except the command to test that it worked.

```
Get-MailContact | Select randomemail@email.com | Select -UseMapiRichTextFormat
```

What is the reason for this failure?

> Select-Object : **A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter**
>   **name** '**UseMapiRichTextFormat**'. At line:1 char:62 + ... t 1 Select
>   support@solidpe.maxdesk.us 1 Select -UseMapiRichTextFormat +
>   ---------------------- + CategoryInfo : **InvalidArgument**: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   **NamedParameterNotFound**,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: What failure? You misunderstood the usage of [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @MrAdmin, do you mean this? `Select  -Property UseMapiRichTextFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually need is this:

```
Get-MailContact | 
    Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -eq 'randomemail@email.com'} | 
    Select-Object -Property UseMapiRichTextFormat
```

`Where-Object` limits the result set by comparing each contact's `ExternalEmailAddress` property and only including the objects that match in the output (which should only be one)

`Select-Object` limits the **output object members** to a subset of the original members